# Change URL and call redux action to get the data in react redux application

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux, react-router-redux

can anyone tell me how to call an action when you change the URL of the Route in server side react redux component with react-router for routing.

I am using **browserHistory** of react-router to push my inputs to url.

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

class findBirthdays extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  openCalender(){
    // here I open the date picker and let user select the date
    // then I add that date in the URL as "localhost:3000/find/?date=22-02-2017"
    // here I get confused as I do not know now how to dispatch the action or
    // how to access url params in a specific actions after dispatching that action
  }

  render(){
    return (
      // repeating all the birthday that are available on selected date
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    birthdayList: state.birthdays,
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(findBirthdays);
```

I have many inputs and on every input change event, will be appending the URL and that should lead to dispatching an action and getting the proper results.

I am new to react and redux, so if anyone can suggest if this can be done or how to approach this problem that would be helpful.
Thanks guys.

Comment: So you want to `dispatch` an `action` or just change the `route` with `date-query`?

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja If I select the date, it should add to url and that url change should dispatch the action which will take the url parameters for further process. I have done the adding it to url part. I need help with the second part.

Comment: You can read url query params like `this.props.location.query.date`

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja I want to read it in an action not in react component.

Comment: Then send this as a parameter while dispatching your action.

Comment: @jyothiBabuAraja I know that, but I am using a module called react-redux-router that is dispatching a default action 'LOCATION_CHANGE' on url change. I want to handle it on this action. I get each and every query too, but I get it in the reducer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136306/discussion-between-nitind-and-jyothi-babu-araja).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys I missed something in my code, I solved this by following ways,

1. Whenever I will change input I will dispatch an action and update the URL.

   - so in above example, I will dispatch an action in

> openCalender() function after selecting the date.

2. When a user wants to change the URL manually then I handle that on the server side.

   - When user will change the URL and press enter that means server renders the whole new page.
   - I am dispatching a default action on page load with,

> this.props.location.query

params, which provided by react-redux-router.

Answer (score 0):

when URL changes  componentWillRecevieProps will call automatically there you can access nextProps then you can dispatch any action you want

in nextProps you can access location that has everything u need about url